# redirect subdomain to same subdomain url in ngnix

Tags: redirect, nginx, url-rewriting

I have multi subdomain in an application.I want to redirect one of the subdomain `(mysubdomain.example.com)` to a url of the same subdomain (`mysubdomain.example.com/fa/news`)

I added this rule to nginx configs.

```
location / {
   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
   if ($http_host ~ "mysubdomain.example.com")
   {
      rewrite ^/$ http://mysubdomain.example.com/fa/news permanent;
   }
}
```

As i change `http://mysubdomain.example.com/fa/news;` to `http://example.com/fa/news;` it works ,but in the same subdomain it throws nginx 404 error.

How i can solve it?

Comment: Can you specify in more detail...

Comment: @LakshmiPrasanna what details do you need? I edited my question to clarify it.